# обрезка строки в php до символа под номером

Tags: php, строки

Как обрезать строку в php до конкретного символа?

Comment: Идите сюда http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php

Answer (score 1):

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

Возвращает подстроку строки string, начинающейся с start символа по счету и длиной length символов.